# Fstab modifications causes boot into emergency mode

Tags: fstab

The Problem:
The changes I made in Fstab (three lines) cause the computer to boot into a command line in emergency mode.

What I have done so far:

1. I have studied the changes that I made following instructions from "info fstab" and numerous online tutorials from respected sites. I cannot see where I made any syntax errors. The mount points I specified do exist.  The hard drive information is correct. The file system on all the hard drives is ext4.
2. I tried using UUIDs (obtained from BLKID) initially and first encountered the problem. So I switched to disk names with no change in the results.
3. I tried using both "sda" instead of "sda1" but that did not change the result.  All the hard drives have only one partition.
4. I search the internet and stack exchange for a similar problem going back 6 months (earlier might not be usefull because I am using Mint 19.3). There are thousands of Fstab and emergency more questions but only a handful were similar to my problem.  The solutions to those problems did not really relate to my situation.  For one thing, I DO NOT dual boot. I only have Mint 19.3 on this computer.
5. I checked the file systems on the three disks. I mounted each one manually and looked for errors. None to be found and they work perfectly when manually mounted.
   6.I now have three days into this mainly because it takes forever to do a live boot from a DVD and I do not know how to use vim to edit the file while on the command line.  I cannot solve this on my own.

Relevant Data:
The motherboard is Gigabyte Z390 Auros Pro Wifi.  So far it seem compatible with LINUX except I can't control the leds and fans etc that require Gigabyte software.  But I didn't buy it for the leds so I don't care.

1. Contents of Fstab with my added new lines commented out:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=7F98-B65E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/sda1  /home/q/Data        ext4                       0  1
#/dev/sdb1  /home/q             ext4                       0  1
#/dev/sdc1  /home/q             ext4       noatime         0  0
```

2. BlkID output:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="7F98-B65E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="7d5fe466-2a44-421e-be0b-a3600286fd22"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="fFiJXn-yCCi-NoS5-fBOI-pUpD-nEBe-vuYbKa" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="106491db-9533-401c-a07a-b413d8d0a3a6"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Home" UUID="abdb5f5a-d197-49cd-ac9e-9d4d8b42d48e" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Home" PARTUUID="2eb3589e-1670-4b12-9a7d-30f3855a506e"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="1a46a49e-8009-4e07-81ab-4e77ab4ee0e5" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Backup" PARTUUID="2eb3589e-1670-4b12-9a7d-30f3855a506e"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Samsung SSD 860" UUID="7938c2e7-f67b-480a-a387-5def5b089d28" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="35ee9883-01"
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: UUID="4fe5f494-6808-48de-affe-39065ad53331" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: UUID="f2ac1774-150b-4454-a148-4223654558b6" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2019-12-13-16-58-44-00" LABEL="Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon 64-bit" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="1dda4ac4" PTTYPE="dos"
```

NOTE:  The disk labeled "Home" (sda1) is not the "/home" on this current installation, but my home directory on the previous installation. The home directory for this installation is on an M2m SSD on the motherboard (nvme01p2).   I want to mount sda1(Home) within my current /home on this installation. I tried mounting it as /home during install but the installer crashed every time I tried to do that. That should have been a wake up call but I just gave up and let installer do what it wanted to. I assumed there was something unique to M2m SSds that I didn't know about. I have no trouble mounting and using sda1 manually.

3. Output of mount -a:

```
mount: /home/q/Data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

NOTE: This after fixing fstab in a live distro rebooting and then changing fstab back to the modfied version and runnung mount -a.  Trying to pipe the output of mount -a to a text file but it did not work while in the emergency mode.

Some Errors from journalctl -xb piped to a txt file that might be relevant.

```
Line 1073
-- Unit dns-clean.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: home-q-Data.mount: Job home-q-Data.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: Unnecessary job for dev-sda1.device was removed.
-- Subject: Unit dev-sda1.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit dev-sda1.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "0" or missing value
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
-- Subject: Unit console-setup.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Line 1273
-- Unit systemd-update-utmp.service has begun starting up.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI mount[865]: mount: /home/q: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "0" or missing value
Jan 13 12:42:29 q-Z390-AORUS-PRO-WIFI systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-resolved.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

NOTE: I could find no errors for sdc1 but it is not mounted at /home/q. it is mounted at /media/q/Samsung SSD 860

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Or is it perhaps yet another Mint 19.3 nonstandard way of operating?  I had a similar problem with grub where changes to the standard grub configuration file in /etc had no affect (but at least didn't stop the OS from booting!).  I solved that one myself by finding a Mint-specific configuration file in /boot and modifying that.

Comment: Please fix the formatting; an easy to read post will help get more attention and better answers. If you would like I can roll the post back to the version that is well formatted and you can add any changes that you made after that point.

Comment: I tried for an hour. It never formatted correctly no matter what I tried,  I read every word of the code formatting and it simply does not work for me.

Comment: Two of your new lines are missing the `options` field. Just use `defaults` if you don't want to set any options.

Comment: Code indenting-by-four doesn't play well with numbered lists. I added a blank line, <br>, and another blank line before the indented-by-four lines. There's probably a better way.

Comment: They used to have options (noatime) but I took that out because I thought that might  the problem,  I'll try it again and report back.

Comment: Two of your new lines specify the same mount point. That's likely not what you want.

Comment: Thank you; everything you said is correct and now it all works perfectly. I don't see anyway to enhance your reputation?